# How to convert a TCP client-server application to a SCTP one?

Tags: c, sockets, unix, server, systems-programming

I have a client-server application in C programming language that uses TCP connection. Consider just the server side.

The main function is the following:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo *ailist, *aip, hint;
    int sockfd, err, n;

    memset(&hint, 0, sizeof(hint)); //set to 0 all bytes

    hint.ai_flags |= AI_PASSIVE;
    hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hint.ai_addr = NULL;
    hint.ai_next = NULL;
    
    if((err = getaddrinfo(NULL, "60185", &hint, &ailist))!=0)
    {
        printf("Error getaddrinfo %d\n", gai_strerror(err));
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "ruptimed: getaddrinfo error %s", gai_strerror(err));
        exit(1);
    }
    for (aip = ailist; aip!=NULL; aip = aip->ai_next)
    {
        if ((sockfd = initserver(SOCK_STREAM, aip->ai_addr, aip->ai_addrlen, QLEN))>=0)
        {
            serveImg(sockfd);
            printf("Exiting \n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    exit(1);
}
```

`init_server` is the function creating the socket:

```
int initserver(int type, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t alen, int qlen)
{
    int fd, err;
    int reuse = 1;
    if ((fd = socket(addr->sa_family, type, 0))<0)
    {
        return (-1);
    }
    if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse, sizeof(int))<0)
    {
        goto errout;
    }
    if(bind(fd, addr, alen)<0)
    {
        goto errout;
    }
    if (type == SOCK_STREAM || type == SOCK_SEQPACKET)
    {
        if(listen(fd, qlen)<0)
        {
            goto errout;
        }
    }
    return fd;
    errout:
        err = errno;
        close (fd);
        errno = err;
        return(-1);
}
```

As you can see I have used the `SOCK_STREAM` socket that is used for TCP connections. The application works.

Now I want to convert the application to use SCTP protocol. For that I tried to use `SOCK_SEQPACKET` instead of `SOCK_STREAM`. I tried the program both on OSX and on Ubuntu. On the former the function `getaddrinfo` returns the error `Bad hints` while on the latter, the `main` program exit without starting serving (the condition `if ((sockfd = initserver(...))>=0)` is never satisfied).

How can I convert my TCP application to a SCTP one?

Comment: That's because it's called SCTP not STCP

Comment: @user253751 thanks, I corrected it

Comment: Does your operating system have SCTP enabled? Most don't.

Comment: Better reporting of errors would help you. Or stepping through in a debugger to see what fails.

Comment: @user253751 How can I verify/enable it?